# Url rewriting in .htaccess for same page structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I need to put in place some rewrite rules for my website:

Do I need to set-up 2 different rules to match these URL:

```
- https://example.com/en/category/my-item-name
- https://example.com/en/category/sub-category/my-item-name
- https://example.com/en/category/sub-category/my-item-name
```

My actual rule is:

```
RewriteRule en/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ article.php?lang=en&i=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: How do you expect us to answer if you do not say what those requested URLs should get rewritten to?

Comment: And, by the way, the 2nd and 3rd URLs you posted are identical...

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. I am considering that you have to pass `my-item-name` in both cases.

Also please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
Also please place your .htaccess file besides(same folder) where article.php is present.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule en/(?:[^/]*)/(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  article.php?lang=en&i=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule en/(?:[^/]*)/(.*)/?$  article.php?lang=en&i=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```